# Differences between a line in a haskell source file and one in GHCI

Tags: haskell

Haskell newbie here so please excuse if the question is too simple. Its just that I dont seem to be able to get a handle on why some things are ok in a file, but not in GHCI. For example, I have the following lines in a file:

```
showLst :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
showLst = putStrLn . unlines . map show
```

This takes a *m* x *n* array and prints the result on the screen. A very convenient function. However, when I am doing a quick check on GHCI and I want the same functionallity, I try to define the same function in GHCI like so:

```
>> let showLst = putStrLn . unlines . map show
>> showLst [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I get a type error. So I try several variations:

```
>> (showLst [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]) :: IO ()
>> (showLst:: [[Int]] -> IO ()) [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] 
>> (showLst [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]) :: [[Int]] -> IO () -- which us wrong anyway
>> showLst [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]] :: [[Int]] -> IO () -- which is also wrong
```

etc and they all fail. This seems to be a very simple thing to do, but not sure why I am finding this to be so difficult. I must be missing something that is really fundamental. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that due to [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) GHCi defaults type of your list element to `()`:

```
Prelude> let showLst = putStrLn . unlines . map show
Prelude> :t showLst 
showLst :: [()] -> IO ()
```

You can disable this restriction and get general type:

```
Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction 
Prelude> let showLst = putStrLn . unlines . map show
Prelude> :t showLst 
showLst :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
```

Or you can specify desired type manually:

```
Prelude> let showLst = putStrLn . unlines . map show :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
```

Comment: Note that you can also specify a type signature proper in GHCi, with `let showList :: [[Int]] -> IO (); showList = ...`